# JTable en java Swing - me repite la ultima fila de una consulta

Tags: mysql, java-swing

antes que nada espero que me tengan un poquito de paciencia si me equivoco al armar este post y se agradece correciones.

Esta es mi situacion, realizo una consulta sobre un rango de personas a mi DB la cual ya la probe y funciona perfecto y me carga el JTable de maravilla, pero sin usar POO, es decir directamente en un boton, por lo que estoy casi 100% seguro que mi problema posterior tiene que ver con la logica de mi funcion de carga, es decir ahora modifique mi codigo con POO y tengo la consulta separada de la funcion de carga de mi JTable (si es necesario mostrare la parte del modelo) pero estoy convencido y repito, que tiene que ver con mi funcion encargada de llenar mi JTable. luego de realizar la consulta segun con unos parametros para filtrar la informacion, la respuesta que me da es una carga de por ejemplo 100 filas, que es la cantidad correcta de registro, pero lo que hace es tomar la ultima fila y repetirla 100 veces. lo explico con un Ejemplo, supongamos que
esta es mi tabla "personas" en la DB
[pablo, juan, pedro, maria, juana]  la respuesta correcta que deberia darme despues de filtrar seria [juan, pedro, maria] pero lo que me carga en el JTable es [maria,maria,maria] como pueden notar la consulta me estaria dando inicio que entiende lo que debe darme porque me da la cantidad de filas correctas pero la funciona que se encarga de mostrarlo en el JTable pisa esos tres valores con el ultimo registro.

a continuacion la funcion de carga de JTable

```
public void listar(JTable tabla,String x, String z) {
        String[] titulos = new String[]{"id","SECCIONAL","CIRCUITO","cir.Cod.","APELLIDO","NOMBRE","GEN.","DNI","DNI-NUM","CLASE","PROFESION","DOMICILIO"}; // cabesera de la JTable
        
        String a;//filtro uno
        String b;//filtro dos
        a=x;
        b=z;
        modeloTabla = new DefaultTableModel(titulos,0);
        
        List<Personas> listaPersona = modDAO.FiltrarUbicacion(a,b); // llamo a la funcion de consulta, le paso los parametros de filtro y la guardo en una lista
        
         Object[]object=new Object[12];
        
        for (int i = 1; i < listaPersona.size(); i++){
        
            object[0]=listaPersona.get(i).getId();
            object[1]=listaPersona.get(i).getSeccion();
            object[2]=listaPersona.get(i).getCircuito();
            object[3]=listaPersona.get(i).getCircuito_cod();
            object[4]=listaPersona.get(i).getApellido();
            object[5]=listaPersona.get(i).getNombre();
            object[6]=listaPersona.get(i).getGenero();
            object[7]=listaPersona.get(i).getTipo_documento();
            object[8]=listaPersona.get(i).getNum_documento();
            object[9]=listaPersona.get(i).getClase();
            object[10]=listaPersona.get(i).getProfesion();
            object[11]=listaPersona.get(i).getDomicilio();
            modeloTabla.addRow(object);
           }
           
        
       tabla.setModel(modeloTabla);
    }
```

// Notas Extras: esto esta en una estructura MVC. Esta funcion esta en un controlador por lo que entiendase que hay un `DefaultTableModel modeloTabla = new DefaultTableModel();` declarado al inicio de la class junto con variables que instancian al modelo, si hace falta mostrare la clase completa pero me parece que seria mucho y por eso solo puse la funcion donde a mi parecer hay un problema de logica.
Muchas gracias por leer.

Editando post .. funcion de consulta (los parametros de filtro son el campo seccional [a] y el campo circuito [b].

```
public Vector<Personas> FiltrarUbicacion (String a,String b){
    
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection con = getConexion();
    
   
     Vector<Personas> datos = new Vector<Personas>();
     Personas dat=new Personas();
    
    
    try{
        String sql = "SELECT id_Personas,seccional,circuito,cod_circuito,apellido,nombre,genero,documento,doc_numero,clase,profesion,domicilio FROM personas WHERE seccional='"+a+"' AND circuito='"+b+"'";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     //   ps.setInt(1,a);
     //   ps.setString(2,b);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
       
        
        while(rs.next()){
            dat.setId(rs.getInt("id_Personas"));
            dat.setSeccion(rs.getString("seccional"));//en la variable de tipo "seccional" en el setter elegido le cargo la respuesta de tipo String del campo elegido
            dat.setCircuito(rs.getString("circuito"));
            dat.setCircuito_cod(rs.getString("cod_circuito"));
            dat.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
            dat.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            dat.setGenero(rs.getString("genero"));
            dat.setTipo_documento(rs.getString("documento"));// en la variable de tipo "documento en el setter elegido le cargo la respuesta de tipo String del campo elegido
            dat.setNum_documento(rs.getInt("doc_numero"));
            dat.setClase(rs.getInt("clase"));
            dat.setProfesion(rs.getString("profesion"));
            dat.setDomicilio(rs.getString("domicilio"));
            
            datos.add(dat);
                    
           }
        
            rs.close();
       
        }catch(SQLException e){
                System.err.println(e);
              
            }
        return datos;
```

Comment: El código que mostraste y devuelve los datos correctamente. Quizás podrías mostrar en el método de filtrado FiltrarUbicacion(a,b) y mostrar también que son los parámetros a y b que estas pasando. Pues al parecer el filtro devuelve los datos duplicados y el bucle que mostraste simplemente esta agregando los datos a la tabla.

Comment: hola, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ver el codigo, ahi agregue la funcion y lo que significa los parametros a y b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estas agregando diferentes personas, estas cambiándole los datos a una persona y agregándola constantemente a la lista.

Las listas permiten agregar un mismo objeto por mas que ya este dentro de esta; a la hora de devolver la lista te encuentras que está muchas veces repetidos y con los últimos valores que le diste.

En otras palabras es igual que hacer esto:

```
  List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<>();
  Persona persona = new Persona();
  
  persona.setName("Juan");
  persona.setSurname("Pérez");
  personas.add(persona);
  
  persona.setName("Luis");
  persona.setSurname("Fernandez");
  personas.add(persona);
  
  persona.setName("Micaela");
  persona.setSurname("Garcia");
  personas.add(persona);
  
  System.out.println(personas); // hay 3 elementos pero con los datos repetidos.
```

Salida:

```
[Micaela, Garcia, Micaela, Garcia, Micaela, Garcia]
```

Para solucionarlo, la manera correcta seria, crear el objeto `Personas` dentro del while:

```
while(rs.next()){
    Personas dat=new Personas();

    dat.setId(rs.getInt("id_Personas"));
    dat.setSeccion(rs.getString("seccional"));//en la variable de tipo "seccional" en el setter elegido le cargo la respuesta de tipo String del campo elegido
    dat.setCircuito(rs.getString("circuito"));
    dat.setCircuito_cod(rs.getString("cod_circuito"));
    dat.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
    dat.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
    dat.setGenero(rs.getString("genero"));
    dat.setTipo_documento(rs.getString("documento"));// en la variable de tipo "documento en el setter elegido le cargo la respuesta de tipo String del campo elegido
    dat.setNum_documento(rs.getInt("doc_numero"));
    dat.setClase(rs.getInt("clase"));
    dat.setProfesion(rs.getString("profesion"));
    dat.setDomicilio(rs.getString("domicilio"));
        
    datos.add(dat);
                
}
```

Entonces la lista contiene varios objetos con los valores que les hallas dado dentro del `while` y no una única instancia/referencia de objeto.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias estabas en lo cierto, impecable tu explicacion y sugerencia